# Upload local file to azure static web storage container $web using azcopy and terraform local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, azure-storage, azcopy

I have been struggling with uploading a bunch of css/html/js files to a static website hosted on a storage container $web using terraform. It fails even with a single index.html throwing below error.

```
 Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with null_resource.frontend_files,
│   on c08-02-website-storage-account.tf line 111, in resource "null_resource" "frontend_files":
│  111:       provisioner "local-exec" {
│ 
│ Error running command '  

azcopy cp --from-to=LocalBlob "../../code/frontend/index.html" "https://***********.blob.core.windows.net/web?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&st=2022-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&se=2023-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=racwl&spr=https&sig=*******************"  --recursive

': exit status 1. Output: INFO: Scanning...
│ INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or
│ destination doesn't have full folder support
│ 
│ Job 718f9960-b7eb-7843-648a-6b57d14f5e27 has started
│ Log file is located at:
│ /home/runner/.azcopy/718f9960-b7eb-7843-648a-6b57d14f5e27.log
│ 
│ 
100.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 0 Total, 
│ 
│ 
│ Job 718f9960-b7eb-7843-648a-6b57d14f5e27 summary
│ Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0336
│ Number of File Transfers: 1
│ Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
│ Total Number of Transfers: 1
│ Number of Transfers Completed: 0
│ Number of Transfers Failed: 1
│ Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
│ TotalBytesTransferred: 0
│ Final Job Status: Failed
│
```

The $web container is empty. So I placed a dummy index.html file before I executed the code to see if that would make this "empty folder" error go away. But still no luck.
I gave the complete set of permissions to SAS key to rule out any access issue.
I suspect the azcopy commmand is unable to navigate to the source folder and get the contents to be uploaded. I am not sure though.

Excerpts from tf file:

```
resource "null_resource" "frontend_files"{

    depends_on = [data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_blob_container_sas, 
                  azurerm_storage_account.resume_static_storage]
      provisioner "local-exec" {
      interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      command = <<EOT
       
       
       azcopy cp --from-to=LocalBlob "../../code/frontend/index.html" "https://${azurerm_storage_account.resume_static_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/web${data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_blob_container_sas.sas}"  --recursive
      
      
      
      EOT
      }

  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're using incorrect blob container here - `https://***********.blob.core.windows.net/web?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&st=2022-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&se=2023-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=racwl&spr=https&sig=*******************`. Shouldn't you be using `$web` instead of `web`?

Comment: Error message references a log file, what does it contain?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy, I am unable to access that log file as it is buried in the github runner instance. I tried to get it uploaded as an artifact using github action within the yml file. but no luck.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I tried with "$web" as well. I am getting this error now   │ failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot transfer individual
│ files/folders to the root of a service. Add a container or directory to the
│ destination URL

Comment: I even changed the command as shown here ilterally giving the blob name after the $web, same error as I just pasted above  ``` azcopy cp --from-to=LocalBlob "/home/runner/work/azure-static/azure-static/tf-manifests/Infrastructure/../../code/frontend/index.html" "https://***************.blob.core.windows.net/$web/index.html?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&st=2022-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&se=2023-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=racwl&spr=https&sig=***************" ```

Comment: It does look like the azcopy is unable to access the container present inside the storage account. I checked my SAS permissions and they are below ``` data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "website_blob_container_sas" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.static_storage.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = "$web"

  
  start = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  expiry = "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = true
    create = true
    write  = true
    delete = false
    list   = true
      } ```
I dont see anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Per a solution listed [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20350), we need to add an escape character (`\`) before $web. Following command (to copy all files and subfolders to web container) worked for me:

```
azcopy copy "<local_folder>/*" "https://******.blob.core.windows.net/\$web/?<SAS token>" --recursive
```

Without the escape character, it was failing with error: "failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot transfer individual files/folders to the root of a service. Add a container or directory to the destination URL"

```
azcopy copy "<local_folder>/*" "https://******.blob.core.windows.net/$web/?<SAS token>" --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review this and provide an answer. I am going to try this out and keep this thread updated.. in the mean while, let me explain how I fixed this. I simply used the GitHub actions workflows to perform the blob upload and get my static site running.